# angular make an json array from loop

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I wanted to make an json array like below from for loop

```
  { id: 1, itemName: "USA" },
  { id: 2, itemName: "UK" },
  { id: 3, itemName: "India" },
  { id: 4, itemName: "Canada" },
  { id: 5, itemName: "Germany" },
  { id: 6, itemName: "China" }
```

I have writen this code for this

```
  data.Countries.forEach(element => {

        this.countryInfo.push(
            'id:'+i,
            'itemName:'+ element.CountryName);
        i++;
      });
```

but this not working, please help me for this

Comment: Please show the `data.Countries` array. There might be better ways to do what you want.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City-Database/master/Contries.json

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Try the following

```js
this.countryInfo = data.Countries.map((country, index) => 
  ({'id': index + 1, 'itemName': country.CountryName})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
 data.Countries.forEach((element,index) => {

        this.countryInfo.push({
            'id':index+1,
            'itemName':element.CountryName
      });
})
```